# Unable to download app **** could not be installed at this time : craslytics

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I have been pushing ipad beta builds on Crashlytics since a long time.
one of my tester is facing issue with "Unable to download app **** could not be installed at this time" alert view shown.

things i did
1) delete his crashlytics profile, and had him install again.

2) again generated my developer provisioning profile from develoeper.apple.com and pushed a new build to crashlytics. 
asked the tester to delete all the apps and crashlytics, and start fresh from crashlytics email download link. still same error.

3) these error i never heard from any other tester.

above tester guys has, ipad 9.2 and we tried most of the things we can.
please help.

Comment: This is a bit delayed, but Mike from Fabric here. Can you share your device logs? Plug your device into your machine, then to get them: 1) Choose Window -> Devices from the Xcode menu2) Under the DEVICES section in the left column, choose the device3) To see crash logs, select the View Device Logs button under the Device Information section on the right hand panel4) To see the device console, click the up-triangle at the bottom left of the right hand panel to show the device console, then click the down arrow on the bottom right to save the console as a file.

Comment: Did you solve your problem?